# Converting database to RDF using D2RQ

Tags: rdf, marklogic

Using an Oracle database as a source, how do I convert the data from that database to RDF triples to be used in MarkLogic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about MarkLogic, you don't necessarily need a vocabulary. Take the primary keys as subject, column names as predicate, and cell values as object. You can insert that as triples in MarkLogic. It will give you a graph that you can query.

Translating columns into more sensible predicates might be useful though, and you might want to add in things like rdf:types, and subclassing maybe, but all that isn't strictly necessary. MarkLogic can do without that. You can also use Inferencing to alias and/or shorten certain paths afterwards, to effectively build the ontology you are looking for.

With smart introspection on the table structure, you might even be able to scan the database model dynamically, and build a generic conversion.

HTH!

Comment: But how do I do that ? I mean taking the subject predicate and object from the table ? Do i need to convert the database into xml ? and then upload it on marklogic ?

Comment: You could generate RDF (pick any format) out of the tables in some way, and load that with MLCP, but you could also put MLSAM in between, and run SQL from within MarkLogic against the external database, and iterate over the results to convert to triples, and insert these.

Comment: I have used mySql database as my datasource to create a search application in markLogic for which I have converted each row of each table into an xml file and then uploaded all the files to the MarkLogic Search application using MLCP, now I wanna try SPARQL, so how do I proceed ? Do I need to convert XML's into triples using online converters like http://www.easyrdf.org/converter ? or how, kindly suggest. If needed I can share the xml's. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to have is Vocabulary, which is essentially dictated by your ontology (schema). So first fix your ontology and then convert your oracle based data rows into resources (individuals) of concerned ontology.

Once your vocabulary gets fixed you can use various available converters like:

- Google Refine
- http://www.w3.org/wiki/ConverterToRdf

Comment: Thanks Haroon, Can you plz guide me how am I supposed to do that with the vocabulary ?

Comment: I have never used MarkLogic. I just provided you the general approach of RDF conversion. As grtjn pointed out that you can go without ontology. By vocabulary I meant the subject, predicate and object. For all these you can use procedure mentioned by grtjn.